# Date conversion in js

Tags: javascript

Is there a shorter way of converting date e.g. "2021-08-19" to "19 Aug 2021" or i need to every time create a new Date object??

```js
const date = "2021-08-19";

const day = new Date(date).getDate()
const month = new Date(date).toLocaleString("en-US", {month: "short",})
const year = new Date(date).getFullYear()

console.log(day, month, year);
```

Comment: [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) may satisfy you

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/ no, even momentjs says you don't need momentjs anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UK` format with some options for the date.

```js
const
    options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' },
    date = "2021-08-19";

console.log(new Date(date).toLocaleString("en-UK", options));
```